# C# Load configuration from XML file

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a console application which will be triggered by a batch file. The application must have to load the configuration from an XML file for running... Suppose if the batch file sends a parameter "Env1" to the application.. The application should load the "Env1" config only to a c# class through serialization. The XML file format is shown below..

```
<EnvironmentCollection>
    <Environment>
        <Name>Env1</Name>
        <Url>....</Url>
    </Environment>
    <Environment>
        <Name>Env2</Name>
        <Url>....</Url>
    </Environment>
 </EnvironmentCollection>
```

Any help will be appreciated greatly
Thanks

Comment: What part of the task do you need help with? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How to load only the config of Env1 or Env2 through serilization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
var dict = xDoc.Descendants("Environment")
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Element("Name").Value, 
                              x => x.Element("Url").Value);
```

and usage would be

```
var url = dict["Env1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First mark your EnvironmentCollection class as serializable. Then you can use following code to deserialize xml back to object:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes xml file to object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static object DeSerializeFromXML(string filePath, Type type)
    {
        object data = null;
        System.IO.Stream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(type);
            data = x.Deserialize(new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(stream));
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

You can use this function like this:

```
    EnvironmentCollection col = (EnvironmentCollection)DeSerializeFromXML("myFile.xml", typeof(EnvironmentCollection));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, you talk about xml serialization, that would require you have an object model in C# that can handle the xml or you create your xml from the object model: http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173

Another approach, very simple, is to load the xml document in an xmldocument object and query on it: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/using-xpath-with-the-xmldocument-class/

I have provided links to tutorials because from the question i think you could use som background knowledge about the possibilities and not just a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason for you to *load* the configuration to an Xml. .Net has the [Configuration Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) that allows you to work with a configuration in a strongly typed and strongly named manner. You can use appSettings for simple key-value entries or you can easily define your own custom configuration section (see the example in the link).

Having said that, the [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) tool on codeplex makes your life a lot easier. It allows you to define the sections via a graphic add-on in Visual Studio (2010 included) and it will generate the class definitions of the custom sections by itself. Try it out, it is amazing :-)